# Converting if statement to conditional statement

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to convert an `IF` statement as below

```
SET RESULT = IF(C>(X-2), (A+B), C) //IF C< X-2 return A+B otherwise return C
```

to a conditional statement as below

```
SET RESULT = C>(X-2)?(A+B):C
```

I have wrote a code which scan the whole string and look of occurrences of `IF`, `(` and `,`. My algorithm is not working when there more than 1 `IF` statement such as below

```
SET RESULT = IF(C>(X-2), IF(P>C,2,3),C)
```

Here is the code...

```
        string data = "SET RESULT=IF(C>(X-2), (A+B), C)";
        string output = string.Empty;

        int indexofIF = data.IndexOf("IF");
        int obCount = 0;
        int cbCount = 0;
        if (indexofIF > -1)
        {
            string script = data.Substring(indexOfIF, (data.Length-indexOfIF-1))
            for(int index=0; index<script.Length; index++)
            {
                int obIndex = data.IndexOf('(', index);
                if(obIndex>-1)
                    obCount++;
                int cbIndex = data.IndexOf(')', index);
                if(cbIndex>-1)
                    cbCount++;

                if(obCount==cbCount)//Found the end of If statement
                {
                    string tempData = data.Substring(0, index);
                    int count = tempData.Count(f => f == ',');//Get the number of occurences of ','
                    if (count == 2)//There are only 2 commas
                    {
                        int firstIndex = tempData.IndexOf(',');
                        int lastIndex = tempData.LastIndexOf(',');
                        string condtion = tempData.Substring(3, (firstIndex - 4));
                        string trueCond = tempData.Substring(firstIndex + 1, (lastIndex - firstIndex - 1));
                        string falseCond = tempData.Substring(lastIndex + 1, (index - lastIndex - 1));
                        output = condtion + "?" + trueCond + ":" + falseCond;

                    }
                    else //More than 2 commas
                    {

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

I am not sure if this will work for complex scenarios. Is there any better other way of doing this? Perhaps using `regex` or any other string replacement operation..

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

I would:

- Read each character into a small buffer
- evaluate the buffer to look for the word "IF"
- set a flag so you know you are in an IF statement
- clear the buffer
- evaluate for parenthesis
- keep track of opening/closing of parenthesis
- perform any additional logic (such as comma parsing)
- continue until the end of the string

> Perhaps using regex or any other string replacement operation..

`(IF.*?(?=IF|$))` breaks out multiple IF statements but it doesn't handle the additional parsing and requires that the input data follow a strict structure. Keeping track of parenthesis is tricky/impossible (see comments on this answer) and more easily handled by a state machine.

Personally, I like the control/flexibility of a character-by-character parse. Tools like [Code Mirror](http://codemirror.net/) use this approach for parsing source code.

You may find that a regular expression is useful once you have successfully extracted a portion of the string (e.g. to deconstruct a formula like `A + B > C` into its parts).

Comment: Arbitrary nested paren matching is not a regular language, so you won't find a purely regex solution unless you constrain the problem space.

Comment: @RaymondChen - agreed, the only way I could make a regex work was to constrain the input data to a fixed number of parenthesis, which I don't view as a viable solution.

Comment: FWIW, Perl5's so-called "regular expressions", and those in many languages that borrowed from it, actually can match arbitrarily-nested pairs of delimiters, using recursive interpolation.  Not that I would recommend actually doing it.  I don't think C# can, anyway.